# visible-xs-block and visible-sm-block bootstrap 3.3.4 not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Using BS 3.3.4 I've tried hidden-xs-block and hidden-sm-block on divs that still display on iphone 3, iphone 4. The only way I could get it to work was a new class with display:none on the media query but I prefer a using built in functionality. I applied the class directly in the 
`<div class="panel panel-default hidden-sm-block ">` as well as  hidden-xs-block
SEE: http://howlingwolfmedia.com/dev/jrmasonry_btstrp/portfolio.html
right side panel is hidden by using custom class turned off for now so you see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

See [orginal code](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.css) there are only hidden-X and visible-X without -block classes available.

e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-xs {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .hidden-sm {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap doesn't define `hidden-sm-*` classes, there is no need to specify `block` if it's hidden.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to add that parameter to my media query. I thought it was built in. This answers my question.